# How can I get an edit request for full row when in readOnlyEdit and fullRow mode?

Tags: ag-grid

I want to have my AgGrid editable and want to run validation logic before a row is saved. So, basically when a user clicks the cell, enters into edit mode, edits a few cells, clicks away - the row is SAVED (unless validation fails).

I started with setting

```
editType="fullRow"
readOnlyEdit
```

on AgGrid. This allows me to get multiple `onCellEditRequest` events when I click away from the row (=save the row). But ideally I want to receive single event with all edited cells (or a full row data).
Is it possible? Can I request this feature on AgGrid?

Comment: were you ever able to solve this I'm in the same boat

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible i guess no, probably i gave up the idea of having this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onRowValueChanged` callback. This will be called once you save any changes within the row.

[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editing-full-row/).